# Prevent parent UIControl from responding to touchDown events

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol, target-action

I am creating a reusable `MetaControl` that consists of a few sub-controls (see pic). It inherits from `UIControl`, and contains 2 simple `UIButtons` and a custom slider I created. The `CustomSlider` also inherits from `UIControl`.

[image]

In the `MetaControl`'s initializer, I add some target actions that receive events from the sub-controls to inform the `MetaControl` of changes.

```
class MetaControl: UIControl {
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        self.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        self.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderTouched), for: .touchDown)
        self.button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1Pressed), for: .touchDown)
        self.button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button2Pressed), for: .touchDown)
    }
}
```

and then later I put the selector:

```
@objc private func sliderTouched() {
     print("The slider was touched")
}
```

**The problem I'm having is with the `sliderTouched()` event. This event gets fired twice whenever I touch the slider.**

- The first time it seems to be sent from the `MetaControl` itself.
- The second time is the correct event being passed up from the `CustomSlider` itself.

My question is, how can I prevent the `MetaControl` itself from responding to events, while still allowing my `CustomSlider` to send its actions?

I used 2 ways to confirm that it was the `MetaControl` itself which triggered the extra event:

- Commented out the action sending code in the `CustomSlider`. Even without this line of code, `sliderTouched()` is still called:

  ```
  class CustomSlider: UIControl {
       var isTouched = false {
          didSet {
              //sendActions(for: .touchDown)
          } 
      }
  }
  ```
- Replaced the `.touchDown` action with `.applicationReserved`. Since I'm no longer using `.touchDown`, the `MetaControl`'s `.touchDown` event is never called.

  ```
  class CustomSlider: UIControl {
      var isTouched = false {
          didSet {
              sendActions(for: .applicationReserved)
          } 
      }
  }
  ```

Interestingly, the `UIButtons` do **not** cause this same problem. Pressing the `UIButton` does not cause two events to be fired. How can I achieve this same thing?

P.S. The way I am causing the events to be sent from the `CustomSlider` is through a custom `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which is embedded into the `CustomSlider`'s own initializer.

I used this as a guideline: https://www.raywenderlich.com/82058/custom-control-tutorial-ios-swift-reusable-knob

P.P.S I hope I'm not going about this the wrong way-- embedding all these sub-controls into a `MetaControl` that then itself inherits from `UIControl`. The `MetaControl` itself never responds to touch events-- only the subcontrols.  I'm using the `MetaControl` mostly as a container to manage the shared state, provide structure to the layout, and to make the control re-usable. Eventually, I need many of them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to make sure to also override `touchesBegan` in the slider.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
}
```